# Get the number of linked documents to a collection in Arangodb

Tags: arangodb

i have a collection called "channels" and it has documents linked to it in a collection called "posts".

Instead of getting the actual documents, how can i just get a number of how many they are. so i can print out

*"this channel has # amount of posts"*

```
FOR c IN channels
 LET posts= (FOR p IN posts
   FILTER c._key== p.channel_key
   RETURN p)
RETURN merge(channels,{posts})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example, it might be as simple as to group by the `channel_key` and count how many posts fall into each group:

```
FOR p IN posts
  COLLECT channel = p.channel_key WITH COUNT INTO count
  RETURN { channel, count }
```